# Update ggplotly plot's subtitle based on shiny widget inputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I need to update the subtitle of the `ggplotly()` plot in my `shiny` app based on the `shiny` widget input. But when I try to put it inside the text, it is hidden.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    
    shinyWidgets::checkboxGroupButtons(inputId = "intervals_A", label = "Bins:",
                                       choices = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", "(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"), selected = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", "(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"),  justified = TRUE, checkIcon = list(yes = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")))
  ),
  fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    
    p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len)) + 
      geom_boxplot()
    p <- p + labs(title = "Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth",
                  subtitle = "Plot of length by dose"
                  )
    ggplotly(p)%>% 
      layout(title = list(text = paste0('Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth"',
                                        '<br>',
                                        '<sup>',
                                        'Plot of length by'),paste0(input$intervals_A) ,paste0('interval','</sup>')))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a global `paste` as a wrapper. And to paste multiple selections I added comma for `input$intervals_A`

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        
        shinyWidgets::checkboxGroupButtons(inputId = "intervals_A", label = "Bins:",
                                           choices = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", "(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"), selected = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", "(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"),  justified = TRUE, checkIcon = list(yes = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")))
    ),
    fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len)) + 
            geom_boxplot()
        p <- p + labs(title = "Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth",
                      subtitle = "Plot of length by dose"
        )
        ggplotly(p)%>% 
            layout(title = list(text = paste(paste0('Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth"',
                                              '<br>',
                                              '<sup>',
                                              'Plot of length by'),paste0(input$intervals_A,collapse = ',') ,paste0('interval','</sup>'))))
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```